# Sum of biquadrat and square is equal to $2017^{2017 }$. How can I prove it?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Prove that there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$m^4 + n^2 = 2017^{2017}$$

I've tried dividing $m^2$ or $n^2$, but i'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: But $2016$ is a multiple of $4$, @Peter. :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you for the hint, I got it now!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews 
This question is part of the following test: (https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/amsp/admission-test/2017_test_b.pdf) It's no. 8 on the sheet. The test is due on March 31. Make of this what you will.

Comment: I should read more such articles!

Comment: @Andrew I wasn't aware of this. My friend gave this problem to me, and maybe he is taking that test. I will ask him, should this question be removed?

Comment: @jacobyjones  You should not remove an answered question. Moreover, it is interesting and a good test, whether one has a number-theoretical hawkeye.

Comment: @jacobyjones I don't know, I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: @Peter if you want it to be a good test, then surely you want to avoid enabling people to cheat by searching on Google and finding this answer?

Comment: @Misha In the internet-area , it will be impossible to avoid "cheating" if someone really wants it. And if I would not post this answer, surely someone else would do it (here or elsewhere)

Comment: @Peter It is certainly impossible to prevent all cheating, but an answer given here is much more high-profile than an answer given on an obscure forum in Chinese. Moreover, MSE *can* be efficiently self-policed on the matter, so I continue think that it *should* be.

Comment: @Peter see also: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774/contest-problem-policy

Comment: @Misha To avoid this "cheating" it would be better if noone would post such a question here. The "danger" that someone will answer it , is near $100$%. The main reason is that answers potentially bring reputation and reputation brings priviliges and many users absolutely want these privileges, I think you see the point.

Comment: To add a little detail : I did not notice the "contest-math" tag.

Comment: Deleting this for a week. @-ping me if I forget. Sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : $$2017^{2017}=(2017^{504})^4\cdot 2017=(2017^{504})^4\cdot(3^4+44^2)$$